# JQuery Mobile using Listomatic Plugin for paginating a listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

When a user clicks thru to a detail page how do I assign the previous "state" of the paginated page e.g. if user loads the list view (items 1-100) then clicks "View More" listview items (100-200) then clicks on an individual item detail page in the listview, then "goes back" using the back button. How can they return to the last data set of listview items 100-200 they were originally viewing without starting over at 1-100 and clicking "View More" again?

Detail page back button:

```
<a href="javascript: window.history.back()" data-role="button"  data-icon="btn-back" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" class="back-button">&nbsp;</a>
```

Listview page:

```
<div id="artistListPage" data-role="page" class="artists-page">

    <script type="text/javascript"> // listomatic listview layout
    $(document).on("pageinit", function(){
        var serviceURL = "http://localhost/Apps/services/pagination.php";
        var getNumber = function() {
            return $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.loading( 'hide' ) }, //Show spinner
                complete: function() { $.mobile.loading( 'hide' ) }, //Hide spinner
                async: "true",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: serviceURL,
                data: { listomatic: $.mobile.listomatic.prototype.getResults() },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data && data.artists) {
                        var list = '';
                        $.each(data.artists, function(index, artistVal) {
                            list += '<li class="muralGrid" data-icon="true" data-filtertext="' + artistVal.firstName + '">' +

                                    '<a href="artistdetails.html?id=' + artistVal.id + '">' +

                                    '<img src="pics/sm/' + artistVal.picture + '"/>' +

                                    '<h4>' + artistVal.firstName + ' ' + artistVal.lastName + '</h4>' +
                                    '</li>';
                        }); // end each 
                        $('#artistslistview').append(list).listview("refresh"); //corresponds with ul id
                    } // end if
                } // end success
            }); // end ajax
        }
        $.extend($.mobile.listomatic.prototype.options, {perPage: 50, btnLabel: 'More', refreshContent: 'daily'});
        $.mobile.listomatic.prototype.registerAjaxCall(getNumber);
    });
    </script>

    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.listomatic.js"></script>

        <div data-role="content" id="artistListContent">
    <div class="artistslistviewWrap">            
    <ul id="artistslistview" class"muralGrid" data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-dividertheme="b" data-filter="true" data-listomatic="true" data-filter-theme="d" data-filter-placeholder="Search Artist Name"></ul> <!-- data-listomatic="true" -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-id="tabbar" data-position="fixed" id="myfoot" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="tab-home" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="artists.html" class="" data-icon="tab-graffiti">Murals</a></li>
            <li><a href="map.html" data-icon="tab-map">Map</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" class="" data-icon="tab-contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="sponsor.html" data-transition="fade" data-icon="tab-about">Sponsor</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- /navbar -->          
    </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div>  <!-- content -->
    </div><!-- page -->
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a cookie.

Try the following (untested) and see if it works.

In the main page

Add this in the head

```
if ($.cookie('from') == null || $.cookie('from') == 100) {

$.cookie('from', '0');

}    

 if ($.cookie('from') > 100 ) {

 var from = $.cookie('from');

 $.cookie('from', Number(from) - 100);

}
```

after this line

```
success: function(data) {
```

add

```
var from = $.cookie('from');

$.cookie('from', Number(from) + 100);
```

and in your PHP script

delete this line

```
$listOffset = $_REQUEST['listomatic']['listOffset'];
```

and add

```
$listOffset  = $_COOKIE["from"];
```

Hope this helps.